# How to upload a file in Storage Path in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, file-upload, laravel-9

I'm trying to upload pdf file in my project, but the stored result path is **C:\xampp\tmp\phpB52C.tmp** and file name is **LMIkeQyRRYG5sOb27ykUNgIYDYw5WyOxmdu9y3hM.pdf** in path of **Storage/app/bookFiles** and the content in file contains characters(not the real content).
I have two questions below:

1. Where is a secure path (not accessible by browser in production version) to store important files?(like purchasable files)
2. Why is content changed?

Here is my code:

BookController =>

```
public function store(BookRequest $request, Product $product)
    {

      $inputs = $request->all();

      if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $file = Storage::disk('local')->put('bookFiles/',  $request->file('file'));
      }
      $inputs['product_id'] = $product->id;
      $book = Book::create($inputs);

      return redirect()->route('admin.product.book.index', $product->id);
    }
```

Route =>

```
Route::post('/book/store/{product}', [BookController::class, 'store'])->name('admin.product.book.store');
```

I used put method for uploading